# jQuery .position() returns always same position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a simple image slider with (left, right) buttons in jQuery. I animate a div position left and right by clicking a left and right button, but at the end of the images my slider goes further. So I need to check where the end of the images are to stop it.

I try to do this by checking the slider div with *.position()* But it always returns the same position in my console.log.

And if I get the right position of the *#gallery_slider* how can I check if it is at the end or begin of the overflow *#gallery_slider* element?

I made a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ah6yb7bf/1/

**My jQuery:**

```
var slide       = $('#gallery_slider .gallery-image');
var slideWidth  = parseInt(slide.width());
var slideMargin     = parseInt(slide.css('margin-right'));
var slides      = $(slide).length;
var sliderWidth     = (slideWidth + slideMargin) * slides;
var pos             = $('#gallery_slider').position();

$('#gallery_slider').css('width', sliderWidth+'px');
$('#product_gallery .gallery-arrow').click(function() {
    var direction = $(this).attr('data-direction');
    var slider = $('#gallery_slider');

    console.log(pos.left);

    if(direction == 'left') {
        slider.animate({
            'left': '-=' + '200px'
        }, 200);
    } else {
        slider.animate({
            'left': '+=' + '200px'
        }, 200);
    }

});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <span id="arrow_left" class="gallery-arrow blue-ui" data-direction="right">
        <span></span>
    </span>
    <div id="gallery_frame">

        <div id="gallery_slider">
            <a class="gallery-image" rel="group" href="#"><img width="140" height="140" src="http://www.tuinkrant.com/plantengids/bolgewassen/tulpen/thumbs/White%20Dream.jpg"/></a>
            <a class="gallery-image" rel="group" href="#"><img width="140" height="140" src="http://www.tuinkrant.com/plantengids/bolgewassen/tulpen/thumbs/White%20Dream.jpg"/></a>
            <a class="gallery-image" rel="group" href="#"><img width="140" height="140" src="http://www.tuinkrant.com/plantengids/bolgewassen/tulpen/thumbs/White%20Dream.jpg"/></a>
        </div><!--End #gallery_slider-->

    </div><!--End #gallery_frame-->
    <span id="arrow_right" class="gallery-arrow blue-ui" data-direction="left">
        <span></span>
    </span>
</div><!--End .wrapper-->
```

Comment: var pos= $('#gallery_slider').position();
try to put it in click function

Comment: @Paweł Yes that works! I have the position now.

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/ah6yb7bf/2/
you need to put

```
var pos= $('#gallery_slider').position();
```

inside click function. Because you check it on page load when its equal to 0; 
After move you need to check it again.